# subList for arrays - ClassCastException when casting to Generic Type

Tags: java, generics

I've written a small utility method but it always produces a `ClassCastException`, any ideas why? and how to fix it?

```
<T> T[] subArray(int begin, int end, T[] array) {
    int size = end - begin;
    Object[] newArray = new Object[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[begin + i];
    }
    return (T[]) newArray;
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
at org.robert.distance.framework.FacadeTest.testSubArray(FacadeTest.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? That would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Arrays#copyOfRange()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)

```
<T> T[] subArray(int begin, int end, T[] array) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, begin, end);
}
```

Heck, it even makes the whole `subArray()` method superfluous :) It only requires JDK 1.6. If you're not on it yet for some reason, here's an extract of relevance:

```
public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to) {
    int newLength = to - from;
    if (newLength < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
    T[] copy = (T[]) Array.newInstance(original.getClass().getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0, Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: how I tend to forget these useful methods :) (+1)

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the problem is you are returning an `Object[]`. Instead of using `new Object[size]`, you need to create a new array of the correct type. One way to do that is to use [Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).

Something like:

```
<T> T[] subArray(int begin, int end, T[] array) {
    int size = end - begin;
    T[] newArray = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[begin + i];
    }
    return  newArray;
}
```

Comment: How come the array does know what is its component type?

Comment: @Sup: the exact `Class` is always known during runtime.

Answer (score 4):

`T[]` isn't `Object[]` - try `String[] ar = new Object[1];`

You'd better use `System.arraycopy(..)`. And the utility method `Arrays.copyOf` uses `Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);` to create a new array, so combine these two methods to achieve your goal

Update: As noted in the comments, and in BalusC's answer, there is already `Arrays.copyOfRange(..)`

Comment: Another option is using `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)`, possibly performing slightly worse than `System.arraycopy(...)`

Comment: @MarcoS: `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` is only available in Java 1.6+

Comment: @newacct: you're right, but the question did not state any restriction on Java version

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's quite straightforward.  You're creating an `Object[]` array, and then casting it to `T[]`.  If `T` is not `Object`, this cast will fail.

Generics and arrays don't really mix very well.  As ILMTitan says, you can use [Array.newInstance](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)), though then you'll have to have the caller pass an instance of `Class<T>` into your method.  Although a better approach would be to use [System.arrayCopy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) as this seems to be exactly what you're doing here.